# Реально ли: расчет молниезащиты в Ruby (двухмерная геометрия в двух проекциях) с визуализацией?

Tags: ruby, визуализация

Появилась безумная идея: создать на руби программу, которая может сделать (или хотя бы помочь сделать) расчет молниезащиты. В методике расчета разбираюсь, в Руби новичок (до этого был знаком только с мистером Паскалем), поэтому интересует, есть ли инструменты, которые могут такое реализовать компактным кодом, или Руби вообще не о таких "примочках" типа инженерных расчетов на коленке?

Геометрия примерно такова:

- на виде сверху (x, y) построить две точки с указанными координатами и другими рабочими параметрами;
- вокруг них провести радиусы, посчитанные по формуле, привязанной к параметрам каждой точки;
- посередине между двумя точками создать еще одну точку с радиусом;
- провести касательные к двум окружностям симметрично с двух сторон, сначала от первого радиуса к среднему, потом от среднего ко второму;
- заштриховать внутреннюю площадь получившейся сложной фигуры;
- проверить на пересечение данную сложную фигуру и прямоугольник с указанными координатами;
- на виде сбоку (x, z) построить треугольники от трех ранее созданных точек, уклон и вершины которых рассчитаны по формуле от параметров тех же точек;
- провести оптимизацию высоты вершин сложной фигуры из трех треугольников, то есть "положить" точки пересечения треугольников на тот же прямоугольник, что и на виде сверху, только с его координатами на виде сбоку (x, z).

Суть объектов расчета, тезисно:

- стержень молниеотвода создает вокруг себя конус защиты, радиусы которого зависят от высоты самой высокой точки стержня над землей и от указанной защищаемой высоты h (естественно, что радиус равен нулю в самой высокой точке стержня и потом по линейному закону растет вниз до земли);
- в представлении конуса не нужно 3D, нужны две проекции (круг на виде сверху и треугольник на виде сбоку);
- если два молниеотвода стоят рядом, то между ними ровно посередине создается виртуальный молниеотвод с теми же параметрами (посчитанными заново), кроме реальной высоты стержня, затем на заданной высоте h от земли, на виде сверху, окружности (первого молниеотвода, второго и середины) соединяются касательными к двум окружностям (сначала от первого к середине, потом от середине ко второму);
- на виде сверху все молниеотводы, очевидно, представляют собой объект (точку) с координатами и иными параметрами (точек и параметров обычно не так много, чтобы обязательно хотеть тут базу данных), при этом создание еще одного объекта сразу же создает систему из него и соседних молниеотводов методом расчета середины между всеми доступными парами и соединения вершин конусов с этими серединами;
- вид сбоку это срез вдоль по прямой линии между двумя соседними молниеотводами, защищаемая зона представляет собой прямоугольник, поэтому требуется треугольник конуса защиты "уложить" в касание на этот прямоугольник, а в случае наличия двух молниеотводов, нужно уложить на прямоугольник защищаемой зоны "заборчик", происходящий от двух вершин конусов и середины;

Визуализация должна поддерживать:

- обстановку (защищаемую конструкцию) на разных этажах (дискретная смена этажа с выводом его плана);
- отображение мест установки молниеотводов поверх обстановки в виде небольших кружочков (вокруг точки установки),
- отображение защищаемой зоны поверх обстановки в виде прямоугольника, рисование радиусов защиты и сложной фигуры зоны защиты (с учетом касательных до радиусов на виде сверху или соединений вершин с серединой на виде сбоку),
- штриховку внутренней площади итоговой зоны защиты (пересечение радиусов и пространств между касательными и дугами радиусов).

Comment: На Руби можно решить расчетную задачу, если ее можно решить на других языках. Вот нарисовать картинку - это другое дело. Но есть куча библиотек для рисования, в крайнем случае можно картинку и вручную генерировать ( но это отдельные извраты). Если Вы знаете как такое написать на Паскале, то на Руби сделаете

Comment: По поводу расчётной части меня смущает в основном построение касательных, на Паскале я такого не делал. По поводу визуализация, тут важно, чтобы визуализация была не извратом, а удобным и компактным инструментом, ибо мне вряд ли заплатят за эту программу, а при наличии сотен тонн геморроя проще взять учебный проект по-проще...

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что здесь почти никто не понимает Вашу предметную область. Поэтому начните с малого, сделайте код, который делает самые базовые расчеты. Потом усложните.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если коротко: задача однозначна решаема на Ruby

Более развернуто: вряд-ли вы найдете подходящий гем, который сделает визуализацию достаточно простой. В вашем случае, скорее всего, визуализация будет самой сложной частью. По крайней мере, с математикой, точно проблем быть не должно, тут Ruby умеет все то-же, что и другие языки.

Из проблем может возникнуть необходимость, например, вручную высчитывать закрашиваемую область. Это именно та задача, для которой может не найтись гем. Придется руками.

Но, как самый простой вариант, можете использовать canvas библиотеки tk. Это не значит, что нет варианта лучше, но такой вариант у вас точно есть.

Где может оказаться лучше с инструментами под вашу конкретную задачу? В Python, в JavaScript. Но я бы и сам решал такую задачу на Ruby просто потому, что он приятнее :3